# How to get only name of member.roles Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, roles

If I use `.roles` on `message.author` i get roles names, but i also gets their id's. Is there posibility to only show names for these roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `discord.Role` instances, to simply get the role names you can use a simple list comprehension

```py
roles = message.author.roles
role_names = [role.name for role in roles]
```

If you want a normal for loop

```py
roles = message.author.roles
role_names = []

for role in roles:
    role_names.append(role.name)
```

Sample output:

```py
["role1", "role2", "role3", ...]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped